# Why do I need to turn off two breakers to cut power to an outlet?

Tags: wiring

I have to shut off two circuit breakers to this one receptacle only. It doesn't affect any of the others in the lower level except for one meaning I just shut circuit breaker One off.

When I took the receptacle apart, I found two pigtails--1 for the hot and the other for the neutrals. Please note that two wires from the hot pigtail went to the receptacle and only one wire went to the neutral receptacle from the neutral pigtail.

They both had three wires in their respective pigtails. I paired each of them to determine which is hot. Pair one lead to circuit breaker 1, pair 2 lead to circuit breaker two and pair three was dead with these wires going to the next receptacle on the lower level. Pair 2 wires leads to an outside outlet.

I tested them using alligator clips with a circuit breaker finder. Pair two wires through showed it was hot (also used a volt sensor) was in actuality not when I tried to wire them to a receptacle. Pair 2 needed the power from pair one to operate outside. I don't own a multimeter.

So why does it take me to shut off two circuit breakers? Hope this is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter if hot and neutral are the same wire gauge (the breaker must be for the smallest gauge used). I have a bunch of 10AWG neutral on long 20A branch runs, because I had a surplus and wanted to reduce loss.  If mixed, they *absolutely must* run in the same cable or conduit - it is not acceptable to use a hot from one Romex and a neutral from another Romex.

Are you sure you're not looking at capacitive coupling?  If a dead wire runs alongside hot wires, it will pick up a "radio signal" from the other wires, and that phantom voltage can be detected by a very sensitive meter such as a modern DVM.  Usually something will seem "a little off" like it will be 10V lower than every other wire.  The proof of the pudding is to hook it up to a night-light or use a lower-impedance voltmeter, the voltage will vanish like a ghost.

When backtracing circuits, I pull off the hot and neutral, then nut them to a resistor of known value, and then measure looking for that value of resistance.   I don't leave the neutral on the bus because I want to isolate/pair it.

Comment: Capacitive coupling possibly? Went to another receptacle in a different room to replace. Found three 14 red ga wires with one dead, the second hot (used alligator ears to trace it to breaker 2 and third red hot also hot (tested to another which should be paired with the dead one) to breaker 1. This is where I don't understand, it all works when combined to breaker 1. Also works when breaker 2 is not connected. Is it possible that breaker 2 wired was pigtail to a hot wire somewhere in the house? Again similar situation. Problem is know I have to shut off both breakers. Been like this 40 yrs.

Comment: Harper all I was asking is why does it take two circuit breakers to shut off a regular (not split) receptacle? I tried to break it down to what I encountered with the second receptacle. Thank you again.

Comment: @larrypinsky  If it was MWBC, you would see more hots than neutrals.   Given the spaghetti you have been reporting, and his fondness for cross-wiring, it's quite possible you have two breakers are feeding power into the same circuit.  I've had to untangle about 40 circuits like that in an old factory and it took me weeks. If all the splices are in accessible boxes, you should be able to get them all eventually.

Comment: Would buying a multimeter help? First to check voltage of receptacles so that I don't have 240 and to determine co tinuity as well as power of a cable. Thank you all for your help. Outside the four receptacles that I found crossed wires or whatever, the rest of the receptacles appears to be fine and corrected. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: My reco for voltmeters is either Fluke or the $10 cheapies, depending on how long you intend to keep the tool.

Comment: Will do. Tried to rewrite the original which I think is more clearer, but doesn't matter I think you answered it. Again thanks for all and your right it wasn't clearly stated. Wish I took a picture of it.